# AWS Lambda blocking all outgoing URL calls

Tags: node.js, http, https, aws-lambda

Basically the above problem. I see no error in the logs, however when I check the script on a seperate server it just works fine. I'm doing an API call to Watson and a simple (get) call to an IFTTT Maker link. I write in Node.js and use the request module.

Is AWS Lambda blocking the connection of HTTPS URL's and if so, what can I do to surpass this unfortunate event? I've already seen a similar issue on another thread which was solved using the request module, but sadly this doesn't work for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you place the Lambda function inside your VPC?

Comment: Please read my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144688/aws-lambda-invoke-not-calling-another-lambda-function-node-js/39206646#39206646

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Lambda function lives in a private subnet, inside a VPC?

If yes, then it does not have internet access, which means all calls to public servers will time out (see [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)).

In that case, you've got 2 options:

1. Do not launch your Lambda function inside a VPC.
2. Allow your private subnet to access the internet by setting up a NAT Gateway. Example guide [here](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/aws_lambda_internet_vpc.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you for yours. I tried your method, but unfortunately it didn't work. I have made much progress with the VPC's, I created one through the VPC dashboard. According to your guide a NAT gateway is combined with the VPC. So how can I use a NAT gateway and not launch my function inside a VPC?
I'm using the Ireland region of Amazon (and thus AWS), while living in Holland, could this be an issue?

-> request.get('**');

This entire statement is just skipped (i put console logs in callbacks). I tried several modules.
Again, any help would be much appreciated.