# Invoking a Lambda function from another Lambda Function Inside of a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

I have been debugging, configuring and you name it the last couple of hours and i can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I am trying to invoke a lambda function which is just retrieving basic information from ec2. when i test this lambda function in the aws console it seems to be working fine. However, invoking it in another lambda, using following code;

```
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("key1" , "key2");
    AWSLambdaClientBuilder builder = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion("eu-west-1")
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds));
    AWSLambda client = builder.build();

    InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest()
            .withFunctionName("GetWhateverIneed");
    InvokeResult result = client.invoke(req);
```

it simply times out. No response whatsoever... Both Lambdas are connected to the VPC and all subnets

I think it is my new VPC that is causing this problem. My VPC is consisting of:

1 VPC .
 -2x Subnets (1x Private with ipv4 10.0.0.0/17, 1x Public with ipv4 10.0.128.0/17).
 -1x IGW Connected to the Private subnet.
 -1x NAT Gateway connected to the Public subnet .
 -2x Endpoints (One for Ec2, One for SecretsManager)

I have also configured two route tables, 
One for the "public" subnet:
"Routes" ->
Destination: 10.0.0.0/16 Target: local
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0 Target: My Internet Gateway(IGW)

One for the "private" subnet:
"Routes" ->
Destination: 10.0.0.0/16 Target: local .
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0 Target: My nat

I have made sure both of my Lambdas is running on the same VPC, they are both using the same security group:       [image]

This is my first time working with VPC so it is possible that i have missed something.

Comment: The Lambda functions should be attached to your private subnet.

Comment: why my private subnet?

Comment: Worth reading the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-configuring. To quote: Important- If your Lambda function needs Internet access, do not attach it to a public subnet or to a private subnet without Internet access. Instead, attach it only to private subnets with Internet access through a NAT instance or an Amazon VPC NAT gateway.

Comment: And I have done exactly that.

Comment: You could launch EC2 into the Lambda's subnet and security groups with a simple userdata script that used curl to hit a public website. If it works then the problem is specific to your Lambda. If it doesn't work then your route to the internet is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your Lambda function is VPC attached, it needs to be able to communicate via your VPC to the AWS API. Lambdas do not talk to other Lambdas over the network, they initiate requests with the AWS API or an API Gateway, which passes the request on to the Lambda Function.

If you need a VPC attached Lambda to initiate another Lambda, it needs to be able to get to the AWS API or API Gateway via the internet. Alternatively, you can keep it all on private networks by adding a VPC Endpoint to the [API Gateway Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html).

A pattern I follow in similar circumstances is described in this previous post of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969112/6427978

Answer (score 0):

I came across this topic while facing the same issue, and I found a solution that is not mentioned yet, so maybe for the next one looking it helps.

When you have the lambdas in the same VPC, you can add an VPC endpoint, but it does not need to be to the API Gateway service. So to invoke another lambda, go to the VPC settings -> endpoints and create one.

- `com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.sqs` -> Allows publishing to sqs from lambda in VPC
- `com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.lambda` -> Allows invoking lambda in same VPC