# Add role as CloudFormation template in serverless yml

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am trying to invoke a lambda from another, following the example from this answer:

[Nodejs - Invoke an AWS.Lambda function from within another lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754766/nodejs-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-within-another-lambda-function)

The answer says that both lambda functions should have **AWSLambdaExecute** and **AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole** permissions.

Using Serverless, how can I add these 2 roles to a CloudFormation template in `serverless.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Serverless [IAM](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/) documentation,

> By default, one IAM Role is shared by all of the Lambda functions in your service. An IAM Policy is also created and is attached to that Role. Also by default, your Lambda functions have permission create and write to CloudWatch logs, and if you have specified VPC security groups and subnets for your Functions to use then the EC2 rights necessary to attach to the VPC via an ENI will be added into the default IAM Policy.
>
> To add specific rights to this service-wide Role, define statements in `provider.iamRoleStatements` which will be merged into the generated policy.

To invoke a Lambda function from another function, you just need to add the `"lambda:InvokeFunction"` action to the existing IAM permissions Serverless already provides. So an example `serverless.yml` service should have a `iamRoleStatements` section that looks like this:

```
service: new-service

provider:
  name: aws
  iamRoleStatements:
    -  Effect: "Allow"
       Action:
         - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
       Resource:
         - "*"
```

In reference to the other answer cited:

- the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy is already covered by the default Serverless policy;
- the `AWSLambdaExecute` is the incorrect name for the managed policy required (that one only provides S3 get/put access, not `InvokeFunction`); the answer probably meant `AWSLambdaRole`, which provides the `"lambda:InvokeFunction"` permission.