# execute two or more Lambda function synchronously with node.js with API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I would like to execute a Lambda function through API Gateway and within this Lambda function I am invoking 3 other Lambda function and 8 scan queries. The combination of these process will complete my business logic to perform some action and find users to whom I need to send a notification using SNS. The issue is while I am invoking a Lambda function from first Lambda function it will not wait until the inner Lambda function proceed there code. Due to this I could not able to get the answer based on the inner Lambda function and always responding from callback as success.

Comment: Can you post your code sample? I might have some ideas, but I think a code sample may help clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have some code samples, however, I'm guessing you might not be invoking your lambda function properly.
Please refer to [Invoke an AWS.Lambda function from within another lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754766/nodejs-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-within-another-lambda-function)
.

In your case, I think you may be calling the `context.succeed` function outside the scope of the your lambda invocation.

What I think you might be doing:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const lambdaParams = ...
  const lambdaResponse = lambda.invoke(lambdaParams)

  context.succeed(...)
};
```

What I think you should be doing:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const lambdaParams = ...
  lambda.invoke(lambdaParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      context.fail(err); // AWS recommends using the callback instead of context
    } else {
      context.succeed('Lambda_B said '+ data.Payload);
    }
  })
};
```

**UPDATE: Jan 23, 2018** based on a comment received regarding doing it the recommended way by AWS

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const lambdaParams = ...
  lambda.invoke(lambdaParams, function(err, data) {
      // if using API gateway, you may want to serialize the data (i 
      // think the error response too), which requires an object
      // containing either/all statusCode, body, header e.g: 
      // {statusCode: 200, header: {}, body: JSON.stringify(data)}
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null)
    } else {
      callback(null, data) 
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Why are you not using what AWS recommends?

Comment: this was copied over from the answer referenced. I could infact use the recommended approach, but I think what matters from the OP's question is more conceptual, than actual implementation. BTW, I'm updating with the recommended approach too.

Comment: That's much better. :-) Given that this will become reference for future readers, we should always use the right way. `context.succeed/context.fail` is already deprecated. It still works due to backwards compatibility.

Comment: I have tried with both ways but its not working for me..
I have used context.succeed and context.done as well