# Is promise wrapper necessary around lambda.invoke?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda

I have the following `Promise.all` example.

Is the promise wrapper necessary with `lambda.invoke`?

Referenced this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795883/139698)

```
function get1(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            FunctionName: 'myLambda', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
            InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
            Payload: { id },
        };

        lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(new Error('error'));
            } else {
                const result = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    }).catch(e => Promise.resolve({ error: 'Error has occurred.' }));
}

exports.getDetails = list => Promise.all(list.map(get1))
    .then((response) => {
        return result;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('oops ', error);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`lambda.invoke()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) has a callback-signature, which usually means you need to wrap it in a promise, but if you look carefully you'll notice it returns an [`AWS.Request`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) object, which contains a [`promise()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property) method. It also documents that

> If a callback is not supplied, you must call `AWS.Request.send()` on the returned request object to initiate the request.

And for `AWS.Request.promise()`:

> Sends the request and returns a 'thenable' promise.

So your resulting `get1(id)` would look like:

```
function get1(id) {
    const params = {
        FunctionName: 'myLambda', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        Payload: { id },
    };

    return lambda.invoke(params).promise().then(({ Payload }) => JSON.parse(Payload));
}
```

Comment: where would the error-handling I have in place fit into this?

Comment: @Rod the promise is rejected by the API if the request fails, so the `.catch()` in your calling code is sufficient. You shouldn't mask the real error with a `new Error('error')`, which is bad practice since it prevents you from seeing the cause of the issue, so I omitted doing that in my answer.

Comment: How do I add the rejected part? because my catch is not being caught. I can change the error to be more obvious

Comment: `.catch()` is not invoked unless there's an error. The fact that it's not being called means the code is working.

Comment: How/Where can I add a condition based on the Payload before it returns?

Comment: Basically, if Payload is empty, I want to reassign or return something else.