# How can I tell if my promise.all is running in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following `Promise.all` example. I was wondering if it was operating in "parallel" in regards to the `lambda.invoke`? And how can I test if something is running parallel?

Referenced this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795883/139698)

```
function get1(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            FunctionName: 'myLambda', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
            InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
            Payload: { id },
        };

        lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(new Error('error'));
            } else {
                const result = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    }).catch(e => Promise.resolve({ error: 'Error has occurred.' }));
}

exports.getDetails = list => Promise.all(list.map(get1))
    .then((response) => {
        return result;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('oops ', error);
    });
```

Comment: AWS SDK can return a promise for you. Just do `lambda.invoke(params).promise()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could count how many actions are started and haven't finished yet:

```
  let running = 0;

  // Inside of the promise:
  running++;
  lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
    running--;
    console.log(`lambda.invoked finished, ${running} tasks still running`);
  });
```

If `invoke` is synchronous, you get:

```
  lambda.invoked finished, 0 tasks still running
  lambda.invoked finished, 0 tasks still running
  lambda.invoked finished, 0 tasks still running
```

If it is asynchronous you get:

```
  lambda.invoked finished, 2 tasks still running
  lambda.invoked finished, 1 tasks still running
  lambda.invoked finished, 0 tasks still running
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to test would be to baseline how long the call should take, and how long it takes Promise.all to complete. If tasks are executed serially, and each call takes ~1 second, a list of 5 elements it should take ~5 seconds to complete. However, if they are running in parallel, they should take closer to ~1 second (although probably slightly higher due to inherent overhead). Basically, you are checking to see if it completes as quickly as the longest task, or if it completes after the sum of time it takes to complete all tasks.