# Lambda calling Lambda - how to access the payload in the second?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm calling a Lambda from another Lambda asynchronously using:

```
payload = {"id":item['id']}
invoke_lambda = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="process",
                                     InvocationType="Event",
                                     Payload=json.dumps(payload)) # Use InvocationType="RequestResponse" for synchronous run
```

This is likely rather obvious, but I can't find the documentation for it - how do I access the payload in the second lambda defined as:

```
def process(event, context):
    (...)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the second lambda, you just need to do `id = context['id']`. When it's an asynchronous call, `event` doesn't come with the `body` key.

Comment: It would benefit any readers if you clarified the differences between reading from event and reading from context, and in what situations they should be accessed.

Comment: I got this error message `"errorMessage": "'LambdaContext' object is not subscriptable"` if I used context to retrieve payload.

Answer (score 0):

Your payload should be in the `body` of the `event` dict. Try `json.loads(event['body']).get('id')`.

Answer (score -2):

Possible duplicate question -- [Nodejs - Invoke an AWS.Lambda function from within another lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754766/nodejs-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-within-another-lambda-function)

Note, you may want to take a look at Step Functions to prevent Lambda A from incurring costs as it waits for Lambda B to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm doing it in Python - not nodejs