# AWS Lambda - Invoke a method of another lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a method, different than the default handler method, of one lambda from another lambda. But not getting how to do it. It is not clear from the documentation. Here is my code

Lambda function 1: **my_function1**

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lambda_inv = boto3.client("lambda", region_name="us-east-1")
    payload = {"message":"Hi From my_function1"}
    lambda_inv.invoke(FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1236547899871:function:my_function2', 
                        InvocationType='Event', Payload=json.dumps(payload))
```

Lambda function 2: **my_function2**

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("lambda_handler")

def say_hello(event, context):
    print("From say_hello function")
    print(str(event))
    print("say_hello end")
```

I want to invoke **say_hello** method of lambda **my_function2** from lambda **my_function1**. How do I do that? By default it tries to invoke the default lambda_handler method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs - Invoke an AWS.Lambda function from within another lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754766/nodejs-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-within-another-lambda-function)

Comment: @vaquarkhan It somewhat helps but does not answer my question. But jimmone and Branson Smith have answered my question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: intention  here to avoid same question again and again and only one answer will help everyone , glad you found ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda Functions are always entered through the handler function. It is like the 'main method'. Each Lambda Function is its own application, with its own resources, so when you coordinate between them, you will always enter the function through main (the handler), where you can then go anywhere else.

**Remember each Lambda loses all of its resources (Memory and CPU) in-between getting called, so it will always reboot from the handler on each call.**

To get to your say_hello function, you'll need to use some if statements in the handler like @jimmone described. Something like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lambda_inv = boto3.client("lambda", region_name="us-east-1")
    payload = {
        "message":"Hi From my_function1", 
        "request": "say_hello"
    }
    lambda_inv.invoke(FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-east- 1:1236547899871:function:my_function2', 
                        InvocationType='Event', Payload=json.dumps(payload))


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("lambda_handler")
    if event['request'] == 'say_hello':
        return say_hello(event, context)

def say_hello(event, context):
    print("From say_hello function")
    print(str(event))
    print("say_hello end")
```

If you are just wanting to change the name of the handler, that can be done by editing the Handler option in AWS Lambda. In this case my_function2.say_hello
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can have only 1 handler per lambda function. What you can do is having some if-logic in your handler to call different functions within the same lambda based on the event.