# Return the value gotten from lambda.invoke (NodeJS / Typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm basically trying to invoke a lambda function using the lambda.invoke function i found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754766/nodejs-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-within-another-lambda-function) (in NodeJs), but i want to return the value so i can use it outside the function and make changes to it, rather than just console.log the output. This is the code i'm trying and isn't working:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.region = 'my region';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

var params = {
    FunctionName: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:function:random-function', 
    // the lambda function we are going to invoke
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'Tail',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({"text": 'test 123'})
};

var output_lambda = 'output of lambda'

lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
    output_lambda = String(data.Payload)
    return output_lambda
});  

console.log(output_lambda)
// returns 'output of lambda' instead of the actual output
```

I've tried some other methods and none of them worked as well, i am very new to NodeJs and AWS, so i'm sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, thank you in advance.

Comment: `console.log` inside the invoke's callback function.

Comment: can you please give some more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason i didn't see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754766/nodejs-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-within-another-lambda-function?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-63248448) to the question: [Nodejs - Invoke an AWS.Lambda function from within another lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754766/nodejs-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-from-within-another-lambda-function), that answered my question and all i had to do was tweak it a bit. Here is my new code, and thank you to [Oscar Fernandez Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9766543/oscar-fernandez-sierra) for this answer.

```
const g_LambdaFunctionName = 'name'; // <======= PUT THE DESIRED VALUE

const AWS    = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda;

//
// Expected use:
//
//   // (payload can be an object or a JSON string, for example)
//   let var = await invokeLambda(lambdaFunctionName, payload);
//
const invokeLambda = async (lambdaFunctionName, payload) => {

let payloadStr;
if (typeof payload === 'string')
{
    payloadStr = payload;
}
else
{
    payloadStr = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
}

let params = {
    FunctionName   : lambdaFunctionName,               /* string type, required */
    // ClientContext  : '',                               /* 'STRING_VALUE' */
    InvocationType : 'RequestResponse',                /* string type: 'Event' (async)| 'RequestResponse' (sync) | 'DryRun' (validate parameters y permissions) */
    // InvocationType : 'Event',

    LogType        : 'None',                           /* string type: 'None' | 'Tail' */
    // LogType        : 'Tail',
    Payload        : payloadStr,                       /* Buffer.from('...') || 'JSON_STRING' */ /* Strings will be Base-64 encoded on your behalf */
    //  Qualifier      : '',                             /* STRING_VALUE' */
};

//
// TODO/FIXME: add try/catch to protect this code from failures (non-existent lambda, execution errors in lambda)
//
const lambdaResult = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();

// The actual value returned by the lambda it is lambdaResult.Payload
// There are other fields (some of them are optional)
return lambdaResult;
};



var callingFunc = async () => {

//
// in this example We obtain the lambda name from a global variable
//
const lambdaFunctionName = 'ARN to my Lambda';

// const payload            = '{"param1" : "value1"}';
const payload            = JSON.stringify({"text": text});;

//
// invokeLambda has to be called from a async function
// (to be able to use await)
//
const result = await invokeLambda(lambdaFunctionName, payload);
return String((result.Payload))
};

callingFunc();
```